# Don't set variable if string does not start with six integers in c# 2.0?

Tags: c#

I have

```
string customer_id;
```

In a for loop I assign a value coming from a database request

```
customer = (Customer)records[i];
```

I want to assign customer_id to customer.entityId only if entityId (a string) starts with six integers.

So:

```
string internal_id = "";
string customer_id = "";
Customer customer;
for (int i = 0, j = (response.pageIndex - 1) * _pageSize; i < records.Length; i++, j++)
{
customer = (Customer)records[i];

internal_id = customer.internalId;
customer_id = customer.entityId;
}
```

If entityId is something like xxyyzz then ignore it, if it is 123456 xxyyzz then assign the two variables. How do I best perform this check?

Thanks in advance

Comment: sounds like a job for a regex: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prasad_1/regexppsd12062005021717am/regexppsd.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^\d{6}.*")
```

This searches for

1. start of string - `^`
2. 6 digits - `\d{6}`
3. any following characters - `.*`

...and returns true in the case of a match.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Regex.IMatch(customer.entityId, @"^\d{6}"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a non-regex solution:

```
if (int.TryParse(customer.entityId.Substring(0, 6), out customer_id)) {
    internal_id = customer.internalId;
}
```

Comment: But that's going to match negative numbers ("-12345xyz"), positive numbers, ("+12345xyz"), and leading and trailing spaces (" 1234 xyz").

Comment: @Jim: Hmm, I hadn't thought of that. Best to only use this if the input is guaranteed to start with either six digits or contain letters in the first six characters.